# Give an example of a graph $G$ such that $G$ and $G'$ are not Eulerian, but $G$ has an Eulerian trail and $G'$ does not have an Eulerian trail.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

Give an example of a graph $G$ such that $G$ and $G'$ are not Eulerian, but $G$ has an Eulerian trail and $G'$ does not have an Eulerian trail.

I was thinking that $T_n$ is not Eulerian but it does contain an Eulerian trail. On the other hand $T_n'$ is not Eulerian and does not contain an Eulerian trail. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you please recall what $T_n$ and $T_n‘$ denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a connected graph has an Eulerian cycle, if and only if all its vertices have even degree and an Eulerian trail, if and only if all vertices besides exactly zero or exactly two have even degree.

Using this characterization one immediately sees that

- The cycles $C_n$ are graphs with an Eulerian cycle, and hence Eulerian trails as well.
- The paths $P_n$ are graphs without an Eulerian cycle but with an Eulerian trail.
- The stars $S_n$ with $n\geq 3$ neither have an Eulerian cycle nor an Eulerian trail. In fact any tree with more than two leaves does the job.

Comment: Aren’t all Eulerian cycles Eulerian trails? Eulerian cycles just have the property that the start and end vertex are the same...

Comment: You were right, I got the convention wrong. Thanks!

Comment: np! thanks for catching my mistake too

Answer (score 1):

Take $G=K_4$ but with any two edges removed. Take $G'$ to be the star graph $S_3$.

Since $G$ is connected and has a vertex with degree three, then $G$ cannot contain an Eulerian circuit, and so is not Eulerian. $G'$ is not Eulerian for the same reason.

There is an Eulerian trail in $G$, a path that visits every edge exactly once, but there is not one in $G’$.

Comment: How does $G$ have 2 Eulerian trails, if it is disconnected? Maybe I remember it wrong, it’s been a while, but wasn’t an Eulerian trail supposed to hit all edges in one go?

Comment: @PrudiiArca you’re right. got my definitions messed up. will fix this example